# VMWare Workstation high CPU - vmware-vmx.exe to virtual machine mapping

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I am running several virtual machines (around 7 or so) inside VMWare Workstation on a Windows host.

In the Windows Task Manager, I see there is a vmware-vmx.exe process created for every virtual machine that I have.  All fine and dandy.

Occasionally, I see some of the vmware-vmx.exe processes shooting up in CPU usage (because certain virtual machines are doing some heavy-duty processing)...

[image]

My question: is there a way (without actually going into each VM and checking for CPU usage) to find out the offending VMs?  How can I find out the mapping between each vmware-vmx.exe process (that is listed in the Task Manager) and the corresponding VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

Switch to the Performance tab and start the "Resource Monitor". Expand the "Disk Activity" panel. Sort the "File" column. Look for the appropriate vmdk file for the VM you want to kill. The "Image" column will have the "vmware-vmx" process listed. Note the PID.

Switch back to the "Processes" tab and kill the PID.

I'm currently on my Phone so i can't test it out myself so no prove on it.